# Подсчет продолжительности игры

Tags: delphi

Делаем игру на Delphi 7.0. Игра аналогична игре "Пятнашки", только вместо цифр нужно собирать изображение по кускам. Нужно вставить таймер, чтобы по окончанию сбора картинки выскакивало сообщение с поздравлениями и обще время сбора. Как сделать вот это время?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так:

```
var
  start: TDateTime;
begin
  start := Now;
  //
  //  Тут основной код
  //
  ShowMessage(DateTimeToStr(start - Now));
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте дополнительный поток (thread), который будет отсчитывать время и помещать его в TLabel. Окончание сборки остановит поток. В Дельфях имеется специальный компонент TThread. А у Архангельского хорошо написано и, даже, имеется похожий пример.

Comment: Объясни как пожалуйста